# Do I need a transit visa in LHR?

Tags: uk, transit, indian-citizens, british-airways

I have a an Indian passport and a valid residence permit for Denmark until December 2016. I am travelling to India from Germany via British Airways. I just have a connection for 2 hours in the UK. Do I need a transit visa?